# Facebook APIs on iOS 5 Beta

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to integrate my app with Facebook and downloaded Facebook-ios-sdk from github. However, the sdk was for Xcode 4.0 code base - I am using Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5 beta 5 application...  Is there a version of Facebook-ios-sdk for the latest iOS 5 beta? If there is, how can I download that?

Comment: Have you tried the current sdk?  What issues did you get?

Comment: Yes!  Downloaded it from the github..

Comment: Yes!  Downloaded it from the github..   There are several errors caused by ARC in the iOS 5 beta..  Got rid of a bunch of these by turning off ARC from the build/compiler settings and had to rename work around the JSON library which is incompatible with that from Google.. I am still not comfortable with this approach - wondering if this is OK or is there an update to the sdk that does not require turning off ARC?

Comment: What you did is pretty much what needs to be done and it's perfectly OK. I doubt theyll release an update of the sdk any time soon, at least until iOS 5 is officially release..

Comment: Looks like Facebook has not yet (21/10/2011) updated their SDK to compile on iOS5. In the meantime, [this solution](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/10/ios5-how-to-turn-off-arc-on-individual-files/) has worked for me.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. Had a go at converting the sdk to ARC but its not so easy. Am going to try the 'don't use ARC for these files' trick. Hard to believe Facebook can't put a couple of programmers on this for a week and deliver some quality for iOS5.

Comment: @RamMadduluri Have u find the solution for this?